# Eulerian graph with odd-degree vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

I'm reading about this theorem.

[image]

But then I see this graph, which seems to be a counter-example,

[image]

with the Eulerian trail being $e_1e_2...e_{11}$, and the odd-degree vertices being $v_1$ and $v_3$.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "Eulerian" in the context of the theorem means "having an Euler circuit", not "having an Euler trail".

Comment: Ahh I actually see the difference now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in a comment, "Eulerian" here means "having an Euler circuit", not "having an Euler trail". Thus your Eulerian trail does not contradict the theorem.